# What is the cheapest way to generate text-to-speech at a slower rate using Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Here is my sample SSML for generating the text-to-speech audio for a word using Microsoft Azure text-to-speech:

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="it-IT"><voice xml:lang="it-IT" name="it-IT-CataldoNeural"><prosody rate="0.8">bene</prosody></voice></speak>
```

My understanding (from the "Pricing Note" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/text-to-speech) is that the billable characters will be this portion:

```
<prosody rate="0.8">bene</prosody>"
```

Is this the cheapest way to do it?

I'm wondering why there isn't a way to set the default speed that does not incur the 30 extra characters per word I'd be billed for.

I'm doing a non-profit language learning app. I feel the default speed is too fast, hence I dropped it to 0.8 for the "normal" speed. I could be generating hundreds of thousands of words (as well as much more in sentences), hence I want to keep the cost down.

Answer (score 0):

I thought only the text "bene" is calculated? This is a big difference with your    understanding?

A way to save money is to generate the SSML with ouput as an MP3 file and play this file. If you use the next time the same sentence. You play the MP3 again and you have no new cost. If you use the Neural voices the cost is higher as for standard voices

Comment: Thanks for reponding. I am writing to an MP3 file that I can reuse. The doc says regarding billable characters: "All markup within the text field of the request body in the SSML format, except for <speak> and <voice> tags". This seems to exclude the "prosody" element, hence my belief that it is billable. Am I mistaken?